# Ubuntu 22.04 root folder claims to have run out of disk space but it is not full

Tags: server, 22.04, gparted, disk-usage

I am running ubuntu 22.04 and gparted claims that my disk is out of space. Gparted claims that the whole drive is full, while sudo du command says on 23GB is being used. I have tried everything to figure out what is taking up the space. Please help.

[gparted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHRwt.png)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-alienware:/$ sudo du -chax --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
12G /var
16M /etc
96M /root
2.0G    /opt
4.0K    /PKGBUILD
9.6G    /usr
23G /
23G total
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to make a backup using rsync to my external hard drive. The path was correct but it ended up syncing to my root drive. This filled my disk. I booted up into ubuntu live cd. Mounted the root partition. Checked for the large files. I deleted the accidental rsync folder and all was good again.